# Playing Plinko on Flutter via Flame

Tags: flutter, dart, physics-engine, flame

I want to create a Plinko game using flutter through flames so that the end result looks like this:

[image]

But this is the only thing I can do:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
        class MyGame extends FlameGame with HasCollisionDetection {
      @override
      Color backgroundColor() => const Color.fromARGB(255, 35, 38, 51);

      List<RectangleCollidable> staticBalls = [];

      void createNewBall() {
        add(Ball(Vector2(230 /*Random().nextInt(31) + 230*/, 0)));
      }

      @override
      Future<void> onLoad() async {
        createNewBall();

        double ballSize = 50;
        int rowCount = 8;
        double gap = 4;
        int staticBallCount = 2;

        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
          double startX = (size.x - staticBallCount * (ballSize + gap)) / 2;
          double y = size.y - (rowCount - row) * (ballSize + gap);

          for (int col = 0; col < staticBallCount; col++) {
            double x = startX + col * (ballSize + gap);
            final staticBall = RectangleCollidable(Vector2(x, y));
            add(staticBall);
            staticBalls.add(staticBall);
          }

          staticBallCount++;
        }
      }
    }

    class Ball extends PositionComponent with CollisionCallbacks {
      double gravity = 200.0;
      double velocityX = 0;
      double velocityY = 0;
      double friction = 0.95;

      double accelerationX = 10.0;

      late ShapeHitbox hitbox;

      Ball(Vector2 position)
          : super(
              position: position,
              size: Vector2.all(20),
              anchor: Anchor.center,
            );

      @override
      FutureOr<void> onLoad() async {
        final defaultPaint = Paint()
          ..color = Colors.redAccent
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        hitbox = CircleHitbox()
          ..paint = defaultPaint
          ..renderShape = true
          ..radius = 10;
        add(hitbox);
      }

      @override
      void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
        super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);

        if (other is RectangleCollidable) {
          if (velocityY > 0) {
            velocityY = -velocityY / 5;
            velocityX = (other.position.x + other.size.x) / 3;
            position.y = other.position.y - size.y / 2 - other.size.y / 2 - 1;
          }
        }
      }

      @override
      void update(double dt) {
        velocityY += gravity * dt;
        velocityX *= friction;

        position.x += velocityX * dt;
        position.y += velocityY * dt;
      }
    }

    class RectangleCollidable extends PositionComponent with CollisionCallbacks {
      final _collisionStartColor = Colors.amber;
      final _defaultColor = Colors.cyan;
      late ShapeHitbox hitbox;

      RectangleCollidable(Vector2 position)
          : super(
              position: Vector2(position.x + 15, position.y),
              size: Vector2.all(25),
              anchor: Anchor.center,
            );

      @override
      Future<void> onLoad() async {
        final defaultPaint = Paint()
          ..color = _defaultColor
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        hitbox = CircleHitbox()
          ..paint = defaultPaint
          ..renderShape = true
          ..radius = 12.5;
        add(hitbox);
      }

      @override
      void onCollisionStart(
        Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints,
        PositionComponent other,
      ) {
        super.onCollisionStart(intersectionPoints, other);
        hitbox.paint.color = _collisionStartColor;
      }

      @override
      void onCollisionEnd(PositionComponent other) {
        super.onCollisionEnd(other);
        if (!isColliding) {
          hitbox.paint.color = _defaultColor;
        }
      }
    }
```

Perhaps there should be a completely different code, but I don't know how to write it. Can anyone help?

Comment: This question is too wide for the stack overflow format, it needs to be more specific.

Comment: If the simulation is deterministic, as this one could be if the timestep is constant, then dropping the ball from the exact same position would always lead to the same series of events. As it happen, you are using a constant for the initial X coordinate of the ball. Try instead to randomize it, so that each ball dropped would take a different path.